# Pass char** by reference from c# to unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

This is the C# code.

```
namespace CameraTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lst = new string[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                lst[i] = new string(' ', 33);
            }
            bool sync = true;
            bool ret = CameraCalls.CAM_EnumCameraEx(sync, lst, 10, 33);

        }
    }

    public static class CameraCalls
    {
        [DllImport("CamDriver64.dll")]
        public static extern bool CAM_EnumCameraEx(bool sync,
                                                   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
                                                   string[] lst, 
                                                   long maxCam, 
                                                   long maxChar);
    }
}
```

The unmanaged method is this.

```
BOOL WINAPI CAM_EnumCameraEx(BOOL bSynchronized, char **ppCameraList, long lMaxCamera, long lMaxCharacter);
```

The method writes to the passed in array of strings.  Is there a way to call this method from c# and have the unmanaged code be able to write to the string array?

Comment: [Marshaling Different Types of Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk9wyw21(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That document had the answer all I had to do was use In, Out

Answer (score 1):

This worked thanks Remus Rusanu that link had the answer.  All I had todo was decorate with the [In, Out] on the lst parameter.

```
namespace CameraTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int maxCam = 10,
                 maxChar = 33;

            var lst = (new object[maxCam]).Select(o => new string(' ', maxChar)).ToArray();
            bool sync = true;
            bool ret = CameraCalls.CAM_EnumCameraEx(sync, lst, maxCam, maxChar);

        }
    }

    public static class CameraCalls
    {
        [DllImport("CamDriver64.dll")]
        public static extern bool CAM_EnumCameraEx(bool sync,
                                                   [In, Out]
                                                   string[] lst, 
                                                   long maxCam, 
                                                   long maxChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tested my answer with `StringBuilder[]` and got stack imbalance error, so I think @HansPassant was right. Still glad my way of creating a new array of whatever objects is already spreading :)

Comment: Well until I added the [In, Out] it didn't work it would either not set the strings or throw memory exceptions.  So if [In, Out] is wrong what is the right way to get the data from the external method?  What should I use instead of long?

Comment: I'm reluctant to spend my time helping. You've answered your own question which suggests you've made up your mind.